# Как можно исключить дублирование в JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хотелось бы облегчить код, но не могу найти нормальных вариант чтоб исключить дублирование Проверок и Функций

```js
function getComponent(component) {

    if (component == 'slider') {
        getComponent_slider();
    }

    if (component == 'text') {
        getComponent_text();
    }

    popupHide();
}

function getComponent_slider() {
    var item = '<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis similique deleniti repudiandae aliquam ipsam natus voluptatibus odit obcaecati provident sequi dolorum, molestiae quod modi corporis, porro, sit ullam mollitia accusantium quos ipsum recusandae aliquid reiciendis, voluptatem vitae.</span>'
    AppendContent(item);
}

function getComponent_text() {
    var item = '<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>'
    AppendContent(item);
}

function AppendContent(value) {
    $('#editor_content').append(value);
}
```

Может кто-нибудь может подсказать? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `объект` (ассоциативный массив), в качестве хранилища описаний компонентов и доставайте их оттуда по имени:

```
var components = {
  slider: "Omnis similique deleniti repudiandae aliquam ipsam natus",
  text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
}

function getComponent(component) {
    if (components[component]) 
       $('#editor_content').append("<span>" + components[component] + "</span>");
    popupHide();
}
```